# Why does the man who guards the Red Heifer defile his clothes?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, derabanan, bava-metzia, parah-adumah

[Bava Metzia 93a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.93a.10) reads: "One who safeguards the red heifer renders his garments impure ... Rabba bar Ulla said: This is a decree, lest he move a limb of the heifer."

But... how does it deter him from moving a limb of the heifer? If the rule was that his clothes would be rendered impure *if* he touched the heifer, that would be a deterrent. But if they're defiled either way, just as a consequence of him turning up for work, what's the reasoning here?

Answer (score 2):

It’s not to deter him from moving a limb. If he moves a limb, he is impure *mideoraita*.

We worry that perhaps the guard inadvertently moved a limb, rendering himself impure. Due to this worry, the sages decreed impurity on all guards of the *parah adumah*, whether or not they believe they have moved a limb.

Comment: Is he impure mideoraita if he moves a limb other than during the course of preparing the animal for slaughter? I'm not so sure.

Comment: Rabbi Martin S Cohen https://zeramim.org/past-issues/volume-ii-issue-3-spring-2018-5778/rabbinic-self-confidence-bending-the-world-to-the-word/ interpreted it as being "to discourage the guard from touching the beast at all, lest he inadvertently induce some blemish in it and thus render it unacceptable for use".

Comment: @zarka Rashi says it’s talking about guarding the animal after slaughter until it’s burnt

Comment: @zarka See Rambam Hilchot Parah Adumah 5:1-2. Anyone who deals with the parah adumah from slaughter until it is burnt becomes impure